# Input multiple user inputs into an array / list

Tags: python, loops, input

Sorry if it's an easy question. But what I need to do is have a script which inputs 5 numbers into an array. For instance the user will be asked 5 times to input numbers from which the mean and sum will be calculated. Is placing the users inputs into an array the easiest way to do it and if so how?

Comment: _Best_ is subjective at best. Best at what, speed? readability? lines of code? It would be more practical to show your code/program with what you're trying to do and what errors/issues you've come across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counter = 0
number_array = []

while counter < 5:
    num = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    number_array.append(num)
    counter += 1

total = 0

for number in number_array:
    total = total + number

average = total / 5

print("The sum is: ", total)
print("The average is ", average)
```

Comment: I know there are better, shorter ways to achieve the same goal. Just trying to keep the code easy to understand. Hope this helps :)